# Програмное определения модели телефона

Tags: java, android, android-studio, model

Есть необходимость определить модель девайса и отправить на сервер для статистики. Как можно определить модель, и насколько это надежно? Если есть ссылки на туториулы, то буду благодарен.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Грубо говоря есть 2 способа:

1) Воспользоваться известной либой [AndroidDeviceNames](https://github.com/jaredrummler/AndroidDeviceNames) - она позволяет разными выкрутасами получить имя устройства, в том числе и с использованием встроенной БД, которая вроде как постоянно обновляется.

2) Запустить `WebView` и оттуда вытащить `user-agent`:

```
String userAgent=new WebView(context).getSettings().getUserAgentString();
```

получите что-то типа:

> Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.2.1; en-us; Nexus One Build/FRG83) AppleWebKit/533.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/533.1

Answer (score 3):

Можете попробовать такой способ

```
String reqString = Build.MANUFACTURER
            + " " + Build.MODEL + " " + Build.VERSION.RELEASE
            + " " + Build.VERSION_CODES.class.getFields()[android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT].getName();
```

Однако, если погуглить, то пишут, что рыночные названия многих популярных устройств недоступны. Есть библиотека, сам не пробовал, [смотрите здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995439/get-android-phone-model-programmatically)